# Pasting a suffix to multiple records sequentially - laravel

Tags: laravel, loops, for-loop, batch-processing

I have a table in which I insert a batch of inputs from a single form. This is done as every entry shares a unique product code, but each entry has a unique serial number. The user inserts the quantity of the batch, lets say 5, and the item is saved 5 times. The controller looks like this:

```
 public function store()
    {

            $data = Input::get();

            for ($i=0; $i<($data['quantity']); $i++){
            $this->repository->saveItem($data, '');


            $initial = Inventory::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->first();
            $batch = Inventory::where('created_at', '=', $initial['created_at'])->get();



        return Redirect::route('inventory.index')->with('flash_notice', "Item Created");
    }
```

I can retrieve the whole batch by finding all records which match the same created_at date ($batch). What I want to do is give each record a unique serial number, which is the product code plus a number (the first entry gets 01, second 02 etc).

My view is this form:

```
 {!! Form::open(array('method'=>'POST', 'route'=>array('inventory.store'))) !!}

 <div class="form-group">
                    {!! Form::label('production_id', 'Production ID', ['class' => 'control-label']) !!}
                    {!! Form::text('production_id', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
                </div>
    <div class="form-group">
                    {!! Form::label('quantity', 'Quantity of chips:', ['class' => 'control-label']) !!}
                    {!! Form::number('quantity', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
                </div>

                {!! Form::submit('Create New Batch Entry', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) !!}
            {!! Form::close() !!}
```

My model is:

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Inventory extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = "inventory";

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $primaryKey = "id";

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = array(

        'serial_number',
        'production_id',
        'created_at',
        'deleted_at',  

    );
}
```

I was thinking about a foreach $i in $batch loop to paste a suffix onto $batch['serial_number'] when the serial number is saved as the production_id from the form. I cannot work out how to paste a suffix sequentially in laravel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$batch->each(function ($item, $index) use ($productcode) {
    $item->update(['serial_number' => $productCode . $index]);
});
```

On another note, it doesn't seem super accurate using the 'latest' created_at date to identify the items from the same batch.
Maybe have a batch table where you first create a new record that gives you a 'batch id' then add that batch id to your new inventory items.

Comment: I agree with this, there's a potential that a timestamp could be a microsecond off and the **extremely** slim possibility of two batches at once during the same timestamp.

Create a table named `batches` that have their own unique ID, then attach an have a `inventory_batches` table, which will contain a `batch_id` and `inventory_id` (pivot table).

Comment: Thank you for both of the comments. I agree with using a pivot table. What I am confused by is how you generate your index to paste on to the product code.

Comment: I have worked out how to get the index, not to worry.